# How to get updated device token in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

Since the device token on iOS can change even after the user has granted push notifications permission, there needs to be a way for me to retrieve the device token when it has updated.

The [react native PushNotificationIOS module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios) provides documentation about how to ask the user for push notification permissions `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();` and how to retrieve the device token when the user allows push notifications using an event listener `PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', (token) => console.log(token));`

But there seems to be no function that would allow me to query the push notifications device token after this. How can I check whether the device token has been updated? How can I retrieve the device token at any later stage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store device token in `Preferences`. Then after get token from `Preferences` when generate new toekn and compare with newly generated token. If both are same then token not updated otherwise store new token in `Preferences` and use it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in `AsyncStorage`, from 'react-native' package after retrieval, like so:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

Then check if it changed every time the app launches, like so:

```
let previousToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
if (!previousToken) {
    // Use token
}
```